# ggplot Geom Histogram is not aligning with left axis

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-histogram

I'm trying to make the first bar of my histogram touch the left axis. I'm not sure whether all the correct values are being inputted.

I currently have this code

```
xlimit = 1000000
upper = max(unique_cd$Total_Medicare_Payment)
mprofiles_over_x <- unique_cd |>
  filter(Total_Medicare_Payment >= xlimit, Gender == "M")
fprofiles_over_x <- unique_cd |>
  filter(Total_Medicare_Payment >= xlimit, Gender == "F")

ggplot() +
  geom_histogram(data = fprofiles_over_x, aes(x = Total_Medicare_Payment, y = after_stat(count / nrow(funique_cd)), fill = "Female"),
                 color = "black", bins = 75, alpha = 0.3, size = 0.1, na.rm = TRUE) +
  geom_histogram(data = mprofiles_over_x, aes(x = Total_Medicare_Payment, y = after_stat(count / nrow(munique_cd)), fill = "Male"),
                 color = "black", bins = 75, alpha = 0.3, size = 0.1, na.rm = TRUE) +
  scale_x_continuous(limits = c(xlimit, 12000000), breaks = seq(xlimit, 12000000, by = 3000000), labels = scales::comma) +
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0, .001), breaks = seq(0, .001, by = .00025),labels = scales::percent) +
  labs(x = "Total Medicare Payment (2017-2021)", y = "% Radiologists") +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("Female" = "orange", "Male" = "lightblue"), name = "Gender") +
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(
    legend.position = c(.95, .95),
    legend.justification = c("right", "top"),
    legend.box.just = c("right", "center"),
    legend.box.background = element_rect(linewidth=.1),
    legend.box.margin = margin(-4, 1, 1, 1),
    legend.title=element_blank(),
    legend.text = element_text(size = 7), legend.key.width = unit(.4, "cm"), legend.key.height = unit(0.4, "cm")
    )
```

This gives me the following histogram. The values look correct, but visually, I don't get why the first left bar of the histogram starts off on the wrong spot.

I tried doing the boundary=0, but it didn't work

[image]

Comment: You are specifying that the leftmost point of the x axis is 1M. If there are no values in your data between around 1M and 2.5M then no bars will be shown. So ggplot is just showing you bars where there is data. I can't verify anymore because you haven't shared a reproducible data set.

Comment: There is data in between 1M and 2.5M. I'm not sure how to share the dataset

Comment: So this is the situation in most debugging scenarios. The computer (R, ggplot, etc) doesn't think there is any data to plot between 1M and 2.5M. You think there is. Somehow, the data you think should be there isn't. Without a fully reproducible example, no one can really help you from afar, but you'll need to investigate what part of your code is causing that data to not be present in the data frame that ggplot is plotting.

Comment: @Chris Lee, to share your data, try using `dput()`. This Q&A about [minimal reproducible examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) might be helpful for adding a bit more info about your data so that we can help

Comment: i think your `scale_y_continuous` is cutting off the bars over 0.001 and leaving those spaces?

Comment: Remove `limits = c(0, .001)` and see what happens!

Answer (score 0):

Though we can't see your data, there's a strong possibility that your taller histogram bars are being cut off by the `limits` argument in `scale_y_continuous`. To demonstrate how this is happening let's create some random data to plot for values above 1,000,000:

```r
library(tidyverse)

xlimit <-  1000000


df <- tibble(a = rnorm(10000, 900000, sd = 2500000),
       Gender = sample(c("Male", "Female"), 10000, replace = TRUE)) 

df |>
  filter(a >= 1000000) |> 
  ggplot(aes(a, fill = Gender)) +
  geom_histogram(
    aes(y = after_stat(count / sum(count))),
    breaks = seq(xlimit, 12000000, 200000),
    color = "black",
    alpha = 0.3,
    linewidth = 0.1,
    position = "identity"
  ) +
  scale_x_continuous(
    limits = c(xlimit, NA),
    breaks = seq(xlimit, 12000000, by = 3000000),
    labels = scales::comma
  )
```

[image]

So far so good. There are counts across all bins from the 1,000,000 filter set threshold upwards. Next step is to add formatted tick marks on y-axis:

```r
df |>
  filter(a >= 1000000) |> 
  ggplot(aes(a, fill = Gender)) +
  geom_histogram(
    aes(y = after_stat(count / sum(count))),
    breaks = seq(xlimit, 12000000, 200000),
    color = "black",
    alpha = 0.3,
    linewidth = 0.1,
    position = "identity"
  ) +
  scale_x_continuous(
    limits = c(xlimit, NA),
    breaks = seq(xlimit, 12000000, by = 3000000),
    labels = scales::comma
  ) +
  scale_y_continuous(
    limits = c(0, .01),
    breaks = seq(0, .01, by = .0025),
    labels = scales::percent
  ) 
#> Warning: Removed 39 rows containing missing values or values outside the scale range
#> (`geom_bar()`).
```

[image]

Then just like your graph, lots of the bars just above 1,000,000 have disappeared! The warning message gives us a clue though - when we limit y axis to 0.01, it can't display the bars above 1% (39 bars are missing). Solution is to remove the `limits` altogether. We still want to create tick marks with `breaks` on the y-scale, but we can set the upper number of the sequencing to any high number (here 1 or 100%) but it will limit the axis naturally without cutting off any bars:

```r
df |>
  filter(a > 1000000) |> 
  ggplot(aes(a, fill = Gender)) +
  geom_histogram(
    aes(y = after_stat(count / sum(count))),
    breaks = seq(xlimit, 12000000, 200000),
    color = "black",
    alpha = 0.3,
    linewidth = 0.1,
    position = "identity"
  ) +
  scale_x_continuous(
    limits = c(xlimit, NA),
    breaks = seq(xlimit, 12000000, by = 3000000),
    labels = scales::comma
  ) +
  scale_y_continuous(
    breaks = seq(0, 1, by = .0025),
    labels = scales::percent
  )
```

[image]